# Json config loader class

Tags: c++, json, classes, static

Currently the class takes a json file and retrieves data from it, and i'd like to improve this class.

## ConfigLoader.h

```
#ifndef LEVELEDITOR_CONFIGLOADER_H
#define LEVELEDITOR_CONFIGLOADER_H

#include <string>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>

namespace Editor
{
    class JsonInit
    {
    public:
        JsonInit()
        {
            std::ifstream inputFile("config.json");
            if (inputFile.bad())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("could not load config file");
            }

            inputFile >> _root;
        }

        inline Json::Value& getRoot() { return _root; }

    private:
        Json::Value _root;
    };

    class ConfigLoader
    {
    public:
        inline static int loadInt(const std::string key) {return json.getRoot().get(key, -1).asInt(); }
        inline static std::string& loadString(const std::string key) {return json.getRoot().get(key, -1).asString();}

    private:

        static JsonInit json;
    };
}

#endif // LEVELEDITOR_CONFIGLOADER_H
```

## ConfigLoader.cpp

```
#include "configloader.h"

Editor::JsonInit Editor::ConfigLoader::json;
```

Edit: forgot to say the "config.json" path is temporary, as i wish to make it possible to let the user choose

Comment: Is the configuration set or does it allow random values. If fixed then I would look at [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) as it requires zero code to load the config file into a C++ object,

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the file `ConfigLoader.cpp` is unnecessary unless you are just providing an example of usage.

The keyword `inline` is obsolete, it is really only a suggestion these days. Modern C++ compilers will make the decision on whether the code should be inlined or not when using the -O3 switch.

If you are going to let the user define the config file name, then pass the name into the constructor and default it at a higher level.